# creating a variable shortcode based on user input that returns (prechosen) variables Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, wordpress-shortcode

I need to update values in all posts of a wordpress installation on a regular base. I was gooing to use shortcodes to insert the request into the wordpress post. Then use a custom functions.php that holds all the variables that need to be updated from time to time.

I got it working. Somehow but not the way I intended to use it. I'm a total beginner. Please consider this when answering my questions.

I want to have a function that reads what comes after honda_ and displays the correct value in wordpress without having to create a separate shortcode for each variable.

When entering [honda_link] wordpress should display the value from honda_link. When entering [honda_longlink] the value from honda_longlink variable should get displayed. I don't want to create a shortcode for each value.

I came up with this as a working solution...

`// Honda`

`function honda() {`

`$honda_link = '`[`www.honda.com`](https://www.honda.com)`';`
`$honda_longlink = '`[`http://www.honda.com`](https://www.honda.com)`';`
`$honda_free = 'Free';`
`$honda_new = '23.688 $';`
`$honda_mileage = '00';`
`return $honda_link;`
`}`
`add_shortcode('neu', 'honda_link');`

I tried some approaches by using an array but it ultimately failed all the time. I also tried it with if statements but wasn't able to get the right value displayed.

Someone willing to help a noob? I think I need to see a working example in order to understand it. The code snippets I have been looking at (that do something similiar but not the same I want to achieve) did confuse me more than they helped me.

Comment: You should not create multiple shortcodes of different names - but _one_, that gets the name of the variable passed as an _attribute_.

Comment: (And instead of individual variables inside your function, an array would be preferable. Then you can simply pass an index/key via your shortcode attribute, use `isset` to check if that exists in your array, and if so return it.)

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to achieve but I don't know how.

He had the same problem but ended by creating different shortcodes for every variable. That's bad practive imho: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/creating-a-variable-for-a-shortcode/

Comment: How to work with shortcode attributes, is explained under https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: I tried something (see answer below) but I'm not happy with the code

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this / Which works in a way but... This isn't very comfortable to use.

```
add_shortcode('HONDA','HONDA_TEST');
function HONDA_TEST($atts = array(), $content = null, $tag){
    shortcode_atts(array(
        'var1' => 'default var1',
        'var2' => false,
        'var3' => false,
        'var4' => false
    ), $atts);

    if ($atts['var2'])
          return 'honda2';
    
    else if ($atts['var3'])
          return 'honda3';
    
    else if ($atts['var4'])
          return 'honda4';
    
    else
          return 'honda1'; 
}
```

So now when using:

```
[HONDA var1="novalue"][/HONDA]
[HONDA var2="novalue"][/HONDA] 
[HONDA var3="novalue"][/HONDA] 
[HONDA var4="novalue"][/HONDA]
```

it shows:

```
honda1
honda2
honda3
honda4
```

and so on.

Is there a better way to achieve the intended goal from post #1 ? Any way I could import the $variables from 1st post in bulk for example?

Comment: That's really quite backwards. You should do `[HONDA model="0"]`, `[HONDA model="1"]` etc. - then you can just use that attribute's value to pick the corresponding entry from an array, `$myHondas = ['honda1', 'honda2', ...]` - `return $myHondas[$atts['model']];`

Comment: And if you want `model="X"` to correspond with `'hondaX'` from your array, then you can start your array at index 1, `$myHondas = [1 => 'honda1', 'honda2', ...]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working WP setup right now to test, but could you try this:

```
add_shortcode('HONDA','HONDA_TEST');
function HONDA_TEST($atts = array(), $content = null, $tag){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'model' => 1,
    ), $atts);

    $myHondas = [1 => 'honda1', 'honda2', 'honda3'];
    
    return isset($myHondas[$atts['model']]) ? $myHondas[$atts['model']] : 'unknown model id';
}
```

And use it with `[HONDA model="1"]`, `[HONDA model="2"]`

Comment: Yes this really helped me to understand it better. This works like a charm, when entering the correct #number in the shortcode, the correct value gets displayed.

I'm trying to add more features like mileage, prices now.

I tried adding  `'model' => 1,
  'mileage' => 1,`

I think I also have to add another variable like `$myMileage  = [1 => 'Mileage 1', 'Mileage 2', 'Mileage 3'];` but I don't know where to put it and how to return it properly mhh. 

I tried this `return isset($myHonda[$atts['model' || 'mileage']]) ? $myHonda[$atts['model']] : 'error';` and it returns error.

Comment: Are you trying to output model and milage separately, in different places, by using the shortcode multiple times - or are you trying to use `[HONDA model="1"]`, and then it should show different information about that model (mileage, new, the links) in one place?

Comment: I'm tyring to output model and milage separately.

Comment: Then you need to figure out a way to determine which argument was passed to the shortcode first of all. I would set the default values to `null` in the initialization of the attributes then, `$atts = shortcode_atts(array( 'model' => null, 'mileage' => null), $atts);` Then you can check after, `if(!is_null($atts['model'])) { ... }` - and inside that if-branch, return the data from the corresponding array. (You will have to create those arrays somewhere, one to hold your model data, one to hold your mileage data. Or a multidimensional array, the details are really up to you.)